# twig looping empty result

Tags: php, model-view-controller, twig

i'm building a navigation menu when I loop the results from database it's working properly with this code

```
 foreach ($menu as $item) {
    echo $item->name_english . ' ';
    if ($item->childs->count()) {
        foreach ($item->childs as $row) {
            echo $row->name_english . ' | ';
        }
    }
 }
```

and this id the output

> first second child1| child2 | third fourth

when I use the same code in twig I get no results from childs loop

```
{% if menu %}
<ul>
    {% for item in menu %}
        <li>{{ item.name_english }}</li>
        {% if item.childs.count() %}
            <ul>
                {% for stuff in item.childs %}
                    <li>{{ stuff.name_english }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}    
</ul>

{% endif %}
```

and this is the output

- first
- second
- third
- fourth

Comment: Maybe `item.childs|length`?

Comment: item.childs|length returns 1

Answer (score 2):

To check the count of an array in twig you use `length` filter. Moreover you should be more specific when using twig. use `menu is not null` instead of `menu`.

```
{% if menu is not null and menu|length > 0 %}
<ul>
    {% for item in menu %}
        <li>{{ item.name_english }}</li>
        {% if item.childs|length > 0 %}
            <ul>
                {% for stuff in item.childs %}
                    <li>{{ stuff.name_english }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}    
</ul>

{% endif %}
```

Comment: Tried this same result, my problem is in the second loop item. Item.childs|length always returns 1 while count returns the number of child items I know there is a result but I can't retrive it